# Can I use "Greater Than" in a SSIS Merge Join?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I don't see any options for doing anything other than an exact match...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That wouldn't be possible with a merge join. The [Merge Join algorithm](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/08/03/687584.aspx) relies on having two sorted input sets and proceeds as follows.

```
get first row R1 from input 1
get first row R2 from input 2
while not at the end of either input
    begin
        if R1 joins with R2
            begin
                return (R1, R2)
                get next row R2 from input 2
            end
        else if R1 < R2
            get next row R1 from input 1
        else
            get next row R2 from input 2
    end
```

If the input sets were

```
input 1                     input 2
------                      ------
  1                           7
  2                           8
  3                           9
```

Then the join `input2.value > input1.value` would return 9 rows (every permutation). However that wouldn't be possible with the algorithm above which does a single pass through each set.